# Shapely coordinate sequence to GeoDataFrame

Tags: python, coordinates, shapely, pandas, geodataframe

Using the shapely bounding box function `box`, and a GeoDataFrameof points, I have extracted a bounding box and created a buffer around it (below `gdf` is a GeoDataFrameof points):

```
bbox=shapely.geometry.box(*gdf.geometry.total_bounds)
bbox=bbox.buffer(5)
```

Now I check and see that `bbox` is a shapely polygon:

```
type(bbox)
shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon
```

My goal is, from this shapely polygon, to create a 1-row GeoDataFramewith Polygon geometry.  I know that I can get all the coordinates that make up this polygon with:

```
[*bbox.exterior.coords]
```

This returns the list of coordinates from a coordinate sequence object which looks like this:

```
[*bbox.exterior.coords][:5]
[(151.20138500000007, -43.787852999999984),
 (-151.40006999399998, -43.787852999999984),
 (-151.89015569564776, -43.76377663336097),
 (-152.3755216040806, -43.69177940201614),
 (-152.85149338027227, -43.57255467866103)]
```

However, I cannot seem to figure out how to convert these pairs of coordinates into a GeoDataFrame.  I have tried:

```
crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
polygon = gpd.GeoDataFrame(index=[0], crs=crs, geometry=[*bbox.exterior.coords])
```

which returns the error:

```
TypeError: Input must be valid geometry objects: (151.20138500000007, -43.787852999999984)
```

How, then, does one make these coordinate pair tuples into valid geometry objects for a GeoDataFrame?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

- Make a shapely polygon geometry from coordinate pairs.
- Pass the polygon to GeoDataFrame constructor as a list.

  ```
  import geopandas as gpd
  from shapely.geometry import Polygon

  coords = [(151.20138500000007, -43.787852999999984),
            (-151.40006999399998, -43.787852999999984),
            (-151.89015569564776, -43.76377663336097),
            (-152.3755216040806, -43.69177940201614),
            (-152.85149338027227, -43.57255467866103)]

  polygon = Polygon(coords)

  gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(index=[0], crs='epsg:4326', geometry=[polygon])
  print(gdf)

  # OUTPUT
  #                                             geometry
  # 0  POLYGON ((151.20139 -43.78785, -151.40007 -43....
  ```